# Refer to both bitmap and state list drawables

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I'm setting up an xml layout that has a button on it, the button has both text and an image on it. To get the image to appear unstretched I refer to a bitmap xml file and adjust the gravity of the image. I also want to change the image on the button when the user clicks it. To do this I have a state list xml file. Both of these components work correctly individually when referred to but I can only seem to be able to do this one at a time. Is there a way to refer multiple drawable files, or a way to combine them into one?

homescreen.xml

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/bHome"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
android:text="Home"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:gravity="bottom|center">
</Button>
```

homebutton.xml

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/homeimage"
android:gravity="center"/>
```

homebuttonclicked.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/homeclicked" android:state_pressed="true" ></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/homeclicked" android:state_focused="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/home"></item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

[State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) gives you the possibility to list several drawables for every button state you want, including normal state and pressed state. Follow this documentation resource to create a proper state list and use it as a background to your image. Hope this helps.